# How do I use OwningRef to construct chains of noise::NoiseFns programmatically?

Tags: rust, borrowing

It seems [the noise-rs crate](https://github.com/Razaekel/noise-rs) has an API design that makes it impossible to construct chains of [`noise::NoiseFn`](https://docs.rs/noise/0.6.0/noise/trait.NoiseFn.html)s programmatically. The borrowing rules seem to constrain me to only use and create a chain of `NoiseFn`s within one function, but not across a function return boundary.

I have received advice that this is unavoidable to some degree, but that one can work around such a self-referential design problem by using the [rental](https://github.com/jpernst/rental) or [owning-ref](https://github.com/Kimundi/owning-ref-rs/) crates. I have chosen the latter due to it having a bit simpler API and usage examples. I have been unsuccessful in its application, possibly due to the extra complication of `NoiseFn` being a trait and the noise crate API being an invariant.

I have extracted some parts of noise-rs into a minimal program that exhibits the problem:

```rust
extern crate owning_ref;
use owning_ref::OwningRef;

// INVARIANT start, copied from noise-rs crate
pub trait NoiseFn<T> {
    fn get(&self, point: T) -> f64;
}

impl<'a, T, M: NoiseFn<T>> NoiseFn<T> for &'a M {
    #[inline]
    fn get(&self, point: T) -> f64 {
        M::get(*self, point)
    }
}

pub struct Abs<'a, T: 'a> {
    pub source: &'a dyn NoiseFn<T>,
}

impl<'a, T> Abs<'a, T> {
    pub fn new(source: &'a dyn NoiseFn<T>) -> Self {
        Self { source }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> NoiseFn<T> for Abs<'a, T> {
    fn get(&self, point: T) -> f64 {
        (self.source.get(point)).abs()
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Copy, Debug)]
pub struct Constant {
    /// Constant value.
    pub value: f64,
}

impl Constant {
    pub fn new(value: f64) -> Self {
        Self { value }
    }
}

impl<T: Copy> NoiseFn<T> for Constant {
    fn get(&self, _point: T) -> f64 {
        self.value
    }
}
// INVARIANT end

// if we can pass Abs::new's argument to the function, we do not encounter borrowing problems
fn make_function_chain_from<'a>(from: &'a (dyn NoiseFn<f64> + 'a)) -> Box<(dyn NoiseFn<f64> + 'a)> {
    Box::new(Abs::new(from))
}

// but if we want to make a function to initialize Abs and Constant all at once, we run into
// unavoidable (?) borrowing problems
fn make_function_chain<'a>() -> Box<(dyn NoiseFn<f64> + 'a)> {
    Box::new(Abs::new(&Constant::new(-6.0))) // error
}

// attempt at using owningref as a solution
fn make_owned_function_chain<'a>() -> (
    Box<(dyn NoiseFn<f64> + 'a)>,
    OwningRef<&'a Constant, Constant>,
) {
    let constant = Constant::new(-6.0);
    let owned = OwningRef::new(&constant);
    // How do you apply owningref here to solve the borrowing problem?
    (Box::new(Abs::new(&*owned)), owned)
}

fn main() {
    // let foo = Constant::new(-6.0);
    // let bar: Abs<f64> = Abs::new(&foo);
    // let baz: Box<dyn NoiseFn<f64>> = Box::new(Abs::new(&foo));
    // let bap = make_function_chain_from(&foo);
    let bak = make_owned_function_chain();
}
```

I am surprised that a Rust crate API that looks straightforward on its face can hoist unavoidable borrowing problems on the API consumer in case you introduce a bit of indirection. The end goal of my program is to construct `NoiseFn` chains based on user input, so using some function indirection or a loop to construct the chain is unavoidable to an extent.

One imperfect solution I have thought of is limiting chain depth to a fixed amount and using `let step1: Option<Box<dyn NoiseFn>> = None; let step2: Option<Box<dyn NoiseFn>> = None;` etc. and later using exactly as many as the input needs all within one function.

Comment: You cannot. `OwningRef` isn't powerful enough (a.k.a. we don't have GATs). Rental can *probably* do it, but that's been expressly forbidden by your requirements.

Comment: Usefully, I think you should file an issue (or a pull request!) with the crate. Ideally, those [noise adapters should take a generic type](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bba43521ce6b634d0582567e9c6ea899). Then you can have the inner value be owning or not. I don't know why they've picked the design they have.

Comment: I remember facing this issue while using their crate. The solution from their side would be to use a `Cow` instead of a reference, but I was to lazy at this time to open an issue. You can have the (crappy) solution to create a global variable (with `Lazy` for example) so that you can have a `'static` reference. Or you can leak a `Box`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. If someone wants to show how you could do it with rental, that is fine, I chose owningref simply because it had more examples. Or do you mean it requires an edit on the crate's side?